# returned json list returning null after deserializing flutter

Tags: json, flutter

'

```
Future<List<ItemModel>?> fetchCategories(String category) async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.http(base_url, '$path/$category'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final items = jsonDecode(response.body) as List;
       print(items);
      List<ItemModel> itemsList =
         items.map((e) => ItemModel.fromJSON(e)).toList();
         
      return itemsList;
    } else {
      throw Exception("Could not fetch courses");
    }
  }
```

this code doesn't return anything. Even though i define class for it. and also it gives json response.the problem is i cant change the returned json array into the object. i refer to a lot of stackoverflow questions. but i cant get any different response. in the bottom i put the response for print(items).

```
[  {category: truck, closing_date: Thu 24 2021,  
closing_hour: 23:23, image:
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1501700493788-fa1a4fc9fe62?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=681&q=80,  
increment: 50, item_id: 61237eb46a27a9571ad912d4, item_name: land cruiser, minimum_price: 4500, user: 61260a5e9}]
```

here is the model

```
class ItemModel {
  final String ?id;
  final String ?itemName;
  final String ?user;
  final int ?increment;
  final int ?minPrice;
  final String ?closingDate;
  final String ?closingTime;
final String ?category;
  final String ?image;
  
  ItemModel({
    this.id,
    this.itemName,
    this.user,
    this.increment,
    this.minPrice,
    this.closingDate,
    this.closingTime,
    this.category,
    this.image,
  });


  factory ItemModel.fromJSON(Map<String,dynamic> jsonMap){
    final result = ItemModel(
      id:jsonMap['item_id'],
      itemName: jsonMap['item_name'],
      increment: jsonMap['increment'],
      minPrice: jsonMap['minimum_price'],
      user:jsonMap['user'],
      category: jsonMap['category'],
      closingDate: jsonMap['closing_date'],
      closingTime: jsonMap['closing_hour'],
      image: jsonMap['image']
    );
    
    return result;
  }

 
}
```

Comment: Please share `ItemModel` class

Comment: i edited the code. added the model class.